# Progress 4GL - get today + 1 day

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, 4gl

Today keyword gives me today's date, but how can add one (or more) days so I can compare it?
I've tried the following code.

```
FOR EACH foo
    where date(today) +1 > end_date
NO-LOCK
```

The error I get is "PREPARE syntax is {FOR|PRESELECT} EACH..."

Comment: The problem is "+1".  The lack of a space between "+" and "1" means that it is a signed constant rather than the addition of one day to today.

Comment: Yes I accidently figured that out when I tried a few combinations. Was thinking I needed to convert to integers first but it worked with just `TODAY + 1`

Comment: As a suggestion, when working with dynamic queries, find a way to display the resulting query to a file or the screen. Grab the query and run it from the editor. It should always work. Can't count the times this (can I call it so?) trick has helped me debug programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just TODAY + 1 - I guess you have a problem in the rest of your dynamic query statement(s):

`hQuery:QUERY-PREPARE (SUBSTITUTE ("FOR EACH foo WHERE end_date < &1", QUOTER (TODAY + 1))) .`

Comment: It was syntax sensitive. I just compared TODAY +1 vs TODAY + 1. The first one didn't work.